# Pfsense Virtual IP subnet to subnet

Tags: pfsense

I have a host in Subnet A that I want to make accessible in Subnet B through a Virtual IP in subnet B and by preference accessible on all TCP/UDP ports.

Comment: What is your question? What did you try? Where did it fail?

Comment: I have tried to create a Virtual IP in the subnet with vlan A / I then added a NAT rule to the IP in the subnet with vlan B.